# How to add classes to each row in datatable jQuery

Tags: jquery, datatable

Hi all i work with datatables,

I want to add class to each table row element in each page.

But for some case is adding only for first page new class, but for other no, how i can to fix this?

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('.table-style').DataTable();

    $('.dropdown').addClass("test")

    table.draw();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add class after the datatable is drawn. This event will be called on pagination or when the page loads. So you can execute your js code or add class on each page. Here is a sample code.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.custom-style').dataTable( {
        "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
            $('.dropout').addClass("test");
        }
    } );
} );
```

For more info see this https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnDrawCallback

Comment: DataTables warning: table id=userRolesList - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

Comment: Did you initailise before running this code. If so, just update the initialisation code and put the "fnDrawCallback" event code there.

Comment: Check this working sample https://codepen.io/ympervej/pen/oNZrOrX?editors=1111

Comment: In ur example it's working, but in my case, it's just add class for first pages :(

Comment: You can edit the pen and test your code there. Or you can  just create a new open and put all of your code there so that I can understand what went wrong for you.

Comment: maybe problem is that, allready on the top code i have func for creating this pagination.

Comment: You can just share me the full code and when time permits I can fix it for you.